# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

Miren, tengo el siguiente error

Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

acá el código del mysql

```
        $sql = "INSERT INTO 
                    topics(topic_subject,
                           topic_date,
                           topic_cat,
                           topic_by)
               VALUES('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['topic_subject']) . ",
                           NOW(),
                           " . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['topic_cat']) . ",
                           " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "
                           ')";

        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if(!$result)
        {
            //something went wrong, display the error
            echo '' . mysqli_error($con) . '';
            die();
        }
```

Y tengo una duda, es posible preparar el mysql sin necesidad de cambiar todo el código ?

Comment: el código completo va en la pregunta, edita tu duda y colócalo aquí

Comment: Hola, por favor edita tu pregunta y coloca el código aquí, no en un sitio externo.

Comment: el código es largo, ese es el problema, 126 líneas, pondré el del mysql que es usado

Comment: Pareciera un error de concatenación, al campo `topic_cat` le hace falta añadir las comillas simples como tiene para el campo `topic_subject`, si es que se tratase de un valor cadena. Igual debe revisar y elegir utilizar sentencias preparadas por la seguridad de su código.

Comment: me acabo de dar cuenta que agregé una comilla que no tendría que estar, la voy a quitar a ver si se soluciona

Comment: ahora sale Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Edita tu pregunta con ese cambio y el error que te devuelve. Sino es imposible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 
                    topics(topic_subject,
                           topic_date,
                           topic_cat,
                           topic_by)
               VALUES('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['topic_subject']) . "' ,
                           NOW(),
                           '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['topic_cat']) . "',
                           " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "
                           )";
```

Tienes un lío de comillas...

Comment: En lugar de `mysqli_real_escape_string` es mejor usar consultas preparadas.

Comment: Tienes razón pero yo solamente cambié la consulta original para igualar las comillas